# NSURLRequest fails on 3G

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following methods to do a NSURLRequest, but it very often fails when im connected via 3G

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest =
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadServer]
                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
             timeoutInterval:15.0];


theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(downloadsUp) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
self.downloadStartTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

if (theConnection) {

    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

} else {

}
```

Connected with WIFI it works like a charm, but over 3G it fails!

Comment: What can you learn from the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods, esp. `connection:didFailWithError:`?

Comment: Welcome to 3G, I guess... ? :P

Comment: What error is occurring in the 3G error case? timeout?

Comment: Of course i implemented the delegates! The Error i get is a timeout! I already set the timeout time to a higher value but it doesnt´t work!